# What is the best way to sit while having food?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, ergonomics, livestrong

I have read various claims regarding the best position to eat: sitting on the floor, sitting on a chair, standing, etc. For example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating:

> Eating while sitting on the floor is believed to be healthier than
>   eating while sitting to a table.

http://www.livestrong.com/article/491625-is-it-better-to-sit-or-stand-while-eating/:

> Increasing knowledge on the effects of standing while performing a
>   variety of tasks indicates that standing while eating may be better
>   for you than sitting.

Are there any studies on the best way to sit while having food?

Comment: (i don't have a general answer) according to Islam, to stay seated while eating is highly recommended. 'cuse, eating should be clean, calm, and careful. on a related note, drinking (anything) while standing is completely prohibited.